# JCodec bitmap to mp4 - distortion in result video

Tags: android, video, mp4, jcodec

When I'm trying to convert a single bitmap to a 10 secs long video using JCodec - sometimes I get a weird result, usually it's a color distortion - or a black diagonal line drawn on the result video. 
here is the code I using (I debugged it and the problem occurs there):

```
SequenceEncoder enc = new SequenceEncoder(f);
for (int x = 0; x < 250; x++) {
     Log.d("frame", "" + x);
     enc.encodeImage(bitmap);
     publishProgress(pb, 1);
}
enc.finish();
```

Here is an example for the both problems (marked in red arrows):

**Original picture:** 
[image]

**After render:**
[image]

Comment: Did you try different image format? If you encoded your input picture as `.jpg`, `.png` and `.bmp`... did one of those formats give better video result?

Comment: Didn't tried yet, i'll try and update here..

Comment: Any solution found for this? I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: i haven't found a sufficient solution for this yet. but i noticed that it happened a lot less when the input image is more saturated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mystery solved after a long period.

If the height or width of the bitmap is not an even number the distortion comes.
JCodec for android is not triggering any error while using a bitmap like this, where as the normal Jcodec will fire an illegal argument exception.

**Solution** : Just resize bitmap to sizes divisible by 2 just before encoding.